# dropdown toggle click only working in center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap dropdown for some purpose. In the template, there are widgets having widget toolbar and widget body.

[image]

I am toggling bootstrap dropdown over this widget toolbar.

```
<div class="widget-toolbar">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle='dropdown'>
            <strong>{{selectedContractDetails.range}}</strong>
        </div>
        <div class='dropdown-menu'>
            <p class="rangeData" *ngFor="let r of service.range" (click)="onRangeSelect($event)">{{r.text}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I click on the `<strong>` tag, dropdown is toggled. Its not taking the entire widget toolbar height and width. If you see the image below.

[image]

There's a padding of 8px on left and right. Because of that whenever I click on the text. The dropdown is getting toggled. Its not working over the padded area. I want the dropdown toggle to work over the complete widget-toolbar. Padding should be there but without removing the padding. I want to toggle the dropdown if anywhere clicked on the dropdown.

Below I have mentioned the CSS of the widget-toolbar.

```
.widget-toolbar {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.09);
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 8px;
    text-align: center;
}
```